# xsl add new elements with namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml :

```
<Row>

<one>1</one>
<two>2</two>
<tree>3</tree>
<four>4</four>
<five>5</five>

</Row>
```

And Im expect to get result :

```
<n0:Result xmlns:ns0="http://www.my.schemas/schemas/event1.xsd"
           xmlns:ns1="http://www.my.schemas/schemas/event2.xsd"
           xmlns:ns2="http://www.my.schemas/schemas/event3.xsd">
    <n1:group1>
        <n2:one>1</n2:one>
        <n2:two>2</n2:two>
    </n1:group1>

    <n1:group2>
        <n2:tree>3</n2:tree>
        <n2:four>4</n2:four>
    </n1:group2>

    <n0:five>5</n0:five>

</Result>
```

My xsl for now is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
           xmlns:ns0="http://www.my.schemas/schemas/event1.xsd"
           xmlns:ns1="http://www.my.schemas/schemas/event2.xsd"
           xmlns:ns2="http://www.my.schemas/schemas/event3.xsd" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="Row">
    <result>
                <group1>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="one|two"/>
                </group1>
                <group2>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="tree|four"/>
                </group2>

                <xsl:apply-templates select="five"/>
    </result>   
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How do I add the desired namespaces to the new and old elements ?
I dont know how to do this with grouping and new elements , only with existing element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write those elements as you literally have written in your desired sample so

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
<result>
            <group1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="one|two"/>
            </group1>
            <group2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tree|four"/>
            </group2>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="five"/>
</result>   
</xsl:template>
```

becomes

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
<ns0:result>
            <ns1:group1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="one|two"/>
            </ns1:group1>
            <ns1:group2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tree|four"/>
            </ns1:group2>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="five"/>
</ns0:result>   
</xsl:template>
```

Obviously then you need to make sure that other templates also output their elements in the namespace you want them to belong to.

A more complete example is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
           xmlns:ns0="http://www.my.schemas/schemas/event1.xsd"
           xmlns:ns1="http://www.my.schemas/schemas/event2.xsd"
           xmlns:ns2="http://www.my.schemas/schemas/event3.xsd" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Row">
<ns0:result>
            <ns1:group1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="one|two"/>
            </ns1:group1>
            <ns1:group2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tree|four"/>
            </ns1:group2>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="five"/>
</ns0:result>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then, as I said, if you transform other elements, you will to add templates, so you also need

```
<xsl:template match="one | two">
  <xsl:element name="ns1:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="three | four">
  <xsl:element name="ns2:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="five">
  <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

So altogether that is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
           xmlns:ns0="http://www.my.schemas/schemas/event1.xsd"
           xmlns:ns1="http://www.my.schemas/schemas/event2.xsd"
           xmlns:ns2="http://www.my.schemas/schemas/event3.xsd" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Row">
<ns0:result>
            <ns1:group1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="one|two"/>
            </ns1:group1>
            <ns1:group2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tree|four"/>
            </ns1:group2>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="five"/>
</ns0:result>   
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="one | two">
      <xsl:element name="ns1:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="three | four">
      <xsl:element name="ns2:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="five">
      <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried that , but if you simply write n0:result in the xsl you will get result with NO n0

Comment: @Ishaked, I have edited the answer and tried to show how to transform the other elements so that they end up in the namespace.